# Inheritance exercise import variables from another class

Tags: python, inheritance, super

In this exercise I cannot work out how to import data from the `Person` into `IndividualBankAccount`.

in the specific this line:  `def __init__(self, sort_code: int, account_number: int, owner: Person):`

I am not sure what goes here

`super().__init__(sort_code,account_number)`

How do I pass the variable owner: `Person`, to the `super()`?

```
class Person:

  _first_name : str
  _second_name : str
  _address : str

  def __init__(self, fn: str, ln: str):
    "creates a new person with first name fn last name ln and empty address"
    self._first_name=fn
    self.second_name=ln


class BankAccount:

  _sort: int
  _account_num: int

  def __init__(self, sort_code: int, account_number: int)-> None:
    '''creates a bank account with given sort code and account number'''
    self._sort=sort_code
    self._account_num=account_number


class IndividualBankAccount(BankAccount):

  _owner: Person

  def __init__(self, sort_code: int, account_number: int, owner: Person):
    '''creates a new bank account with given sort code, account number, and owner'''

    super().__init__(sort_code,account_number)
    self._owner = owner

  def get_account_data(self)-> str:
    '''returns string "FN LN SC AN" where FN and LN are owner's first and last names,
    SC is sort code, AN is account number'''
    my_string =f"{XXXXwhat goes here???XXXX}"
    return my_string
```

Comment: You wouldn't pass it to `super().__init__`, the superclass `__init__` only takes 2 arguments.

Comment: You just want `self._owner = owner` probably

Comment: I have updated the code, I hope this is better now

Comment: Have you learned about f-strings/string interpolatioin? Any string formatting? Or even concatenating strings with `+`? I'm sorry but this is a totally different question.

Comment: I am not asking about how to format the string, I am asking how to pass these variables correctly, I posted just part of the code, in other parts the string formatting works 
my_string =f"{self._sort} {self._account_num}"
If I knew how to do the thing, I would not be asking...

Comment: Do you mean `self._owner._first_name` etc?

Comment: It isn't obvious *what you don't know*. The text in your question has nothing to do with your current problem and is asking about `super`

Comment: You answered it!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person:
  
  _first_name : str
  _second_name : str
  _address : str
  
  def __init__(self, fn: str, ln: str):
    "creates a new person with first name fn last name ln and empty address"
    self._first_name=fn
    self.second_name=ln
  
  def set_address(self, adr: str)-> None:
    "sets the address to adr"
    self._address=adr

  def get_address(self)-> str:
    "returns the address"
    return self._address

    
class BankAccount:
  
  _sort: int
  _account_num: int
    
  def __init__(self, sort_code: int, account_number: int)-> None:
    '''creates a bank account with given sort code and account number'''
    self._sort=sort_code
    self._account_num=account_number
    
    
  def set_sort_code(self, sort_code: int)-> None:
    '''updates sort code'''
    self._sort=sort_code
        
  def get_sort_code(self)-> int:
    '''returns sort code'''
    return int(self._sort)
        
  def set_account_number(self, account_number: int)-> None:
    '''updates account number'''
    self._account_num=account_number
    
  def get_account_number(self)-> int:
    '''returns account number'''
    return int(self._account_num)
    
  def get_account_data(self)-> str:
    '''returns string "SC AN" where SC is sort code, AN is account number'''
    my_string =f"{self._sort} {self._account_num}"
    return my_string

    
class IndividualBankAccount(BankAccount):
  
  _owner: Person
  
  def __init__(self, sort_code: int, account_number: int, owner: Person):
    '''creates a new bank account with given sort code, account number, and owner'''  
    
    super().__init__(sort_code,account_number)
    self._owner = owner
    self.sort_code=sort_code
    self.account_number=account_number
        
  def get_account_data(self)-> str:
    '''returns string "FN LN SC AN" where FN and LN are owner's first and last names,
    SC is sort code, AN is account number'''
    my_string =f"{self._owner._first_name} {self._owner.second_name} {self.sort_code} {self.account_number}"
    return my_string
```